# Objeto ficando null no meio do processo

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema utilizando Java, Maven, Hibernate, PrimeFaces e banco de dados MySQL.
Dentro deste sistema, criei um programa para registrar a quantidade de chuvas que ocorrem no dia.

Minha tabela `Pluviometro` tem os campos para o (código auto increment, local, data e quantidade de chuva).

Quando inicializo a tela, tenho um `@PostContruct` que inicializa meu objeto `Pluviometro`. Após a inicialização, preencho os 3 campos da tabela e clico em gravar.

Ao clicar no botão "gravar" ele chama o método para salvar os dados, mas o objeto `Pluviometro` chega `null`. Será que alguém pode me dar uma dica do que pode estar acontecendo?

```
@PostConstruct
private void startDeTela(){
    PluviometroDAO pluviometroDAO = new PluviometroDAO();
    pluviometros = pluviometroDAO.listar("dataDeApontamento");
    pluviometro = new Pluviometro();
    carregaSelectItens();
}

public void novo(){
    pluviometro = new Pluviometro();
}

public void salvar(){
    PluviometroDAO pluviometroDAO = new PluviometroDAO();
    try{
        pluviometroDAO.merge(pluviometro);
        Messages.addGlobalInfo("Apontamento Registrado Com Sucesso.");
        novo();
    }catch(RuntimeException erro){
        erro.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá! Não ficou claro onde chega `null`. O botão gravar chama qual método? No mais, recomendo evitar este tipo de anotação `PostConstruct`, raramente são necessários e em problemas mais simples acaba mais atrapalhando do que ajudando.

Comment: Olá Dherik, ele chega null no método salvar().

Comment: Como você está instanciando esta classe? Se você fizer apenas um `new Classe()`, esta anotação `@PostConstruct` (do Spring, correto?) dentro dela não vai funcionar.

Comment: Você está usando Spring nesse projeto também?

Comment: Stateless não estou usando Spring.

Comment: O que estou achando estranho é que na minha tela esta carregando os dados do objeto Pluviometro. Acredito que esta chegando correto na tela, caso contrario peso que daria erro de nullPoint.

Comment: Esta anotação `PostConstruct` é de onde?

Comment: Ela é do javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

Comment: Para ter uma ideia, o que fiz para testar. No objeto Pluviometro tenho os campos (Fazenda, Data e chuva). Criei os campos independentes, instanciei-os e na minha tela ao invés de eu apontar diretamente para o Pluviometro, apontei para estes campos. 
Na hora de salvar eu dei um new o pluviometro e setei estes campos.
Esta dando a impressão que o Objeto Pluviometro esta com problema de escopo.

Comment: Tentei mandar o código de como ficou, mas ficou desconfigurado.

Answer (score 1):

1. Facilite a vida de quem está tentando te ajudar e coloque o código fonte completo, junto com o xhtml.
2. No método salvar você está fazendo o merge do objeto pluviometro. Esse objeto deve estar declarado no escopo da classe junto com os gets e sets. E no xhtml você aponta cada campo para os atributos desse objeto.
3. Caso você tenha o CDI como dependência no projeto, utilize ele para injetar o objeto PluviometroDAO com a anotação @Inject. Perceba que no código apresentado existe 2 linhas exatamente iguais para instanciar ele.
4. Se você não utiliza o CDI no projeto, crie uma variável com o escopo global e inicialize ela apenas uma vez através do @PostConstruct. Dessa forma, você evita a replicação de código.
5. No managed bean não é interessante injetar um DAO, levando em consideração "padrões de projeto" . O ideal seria ter a seguinte estrutura (Managed Bean > Controller > DAO)

Se com essas instruções você não conseguir resolver o problema em questão. De uma olhada nesse [link](https://github.com/karanalpe/curso-adminfaces/tree/master/Aula%204%20-%20Criando%20interface%20interagindo%20com%20o%20controller) com um projeto funcional.